# Rails validation - custom error messages with attributes from related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an Expense model with attributes like [`:user_id`, `:activity_id`, `:date`, ....]

Relationships are:

```
expense belongs_to user
expense belongs_to activity
```

And I have the following validation.

```
validates :activity_id, uniqueness: scope: [:user_id, :date], message: "Expense for 'activity_name' on date '1/1/2012' is already entered"
```

How to get `activity_name` and `date` into the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:message` attribute. Here is the inline approach.

```
validates :activity_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:user_id, :date], :message => "Expense for "+ activity_name + " on date " + date + " is already entered"}
```

Comment: That was my question, how to get those values to the message. I will edit my qs if it is not clear

Comment: I like the idea. But I was wondering if there is solution, that is not a work around.

Comment: This seems to be a hack and I cannot do this in my form, which submits multiple nested attributes. I was looking for a solution in the model itself. I have tried using Procs for messages without success. Anyway your approach was good.. :)

Comment: @santhosh inline solution has been found. Please check it.

Comment: I replied after seeing ur edit. I wanted to add my custom error msg from model itself. not add some message and use condition to display something else in the view.

Comment: @santhosh to avoid confusion, two approaches have been separated into two answers. Inline approach is what you need to add your custom message from model itself.

Comment: date and activity name are undefined variables in Expense model.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (non-inline) is:

In model code:

```
validates :activity_id, uniqueness: => {scope: [:user_id, :date], :message => "error is here"}
```

In view code:

```
  = form_for(@expense) do |f|
    - if @expense.errors.any?
      = pluralize(@expense.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this link from being saved:

        %ul
          -@expense.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            - if msg[0,12] == "error is here"
              = "Expense for "+ params[:activity_name] + " on date " + params[:date] + " is already entered"
```

`params[:activity_name]` is the correct way to access the entered data.